# Is a one class naive bayes possible?

Tags: classification, naive-bayes, anomaly-detection, novelty-detection

I have a simple question - I think.

I have recently read a paper:

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~kewang/paper/DMSEC-camera.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiI9um_8LbKAhWDMBoKHSmlDPgQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNFYXFLNLcWt350pbZMKhOB9MJu_Yw

That uses a one class naive bayes. My question is - can I do the same as a one class multinomial bayes when I use a Gaussian distribution.

The above paper used a threshold to identify their class of interest in a test dataset.

If I make the following assumptions:

The standard deviation is greater than one for my features in the training data

Add the log sums of the Gaussian pdfs for all variables for each sample

Could I use a threshold, some standard deviation derived from the normal - maybe 3, to identify data points that are close to my one class training data.

Answer (score 2):

According to the paper [One-class document classification via Neural Networks](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1230310) of Manevitz and Yousef it seems to be possible to construct a one-class Naive Bayes classifier, even without a standard deviation.

I cite the relevant passage where the authors mention how to implement the core of the classifier:

> We calculate $p(d|E)$ as the product of $p(w|E)$ for all words in the
> dictionary that appear in the document $d$. Each of the $p(w|E)$ is
> estimated independently using the formula:
>
> $p(w|E) = \dfrac{n_w + 1}{n + |dictionary|}$,
>
> where $n_w$ is the number of times word $w$ occurs in $E$, and $n$ is the total number of words in $E$.
> We calculate a threshold $\delta$ by the minimum over all examples in
> $E$, of the value $p(d|E)$ for each document in the set of examples.
> Then we experiment with values $\lambda\cdot\delta$ for $0 < \lambda \leq 1$ as in the previous algorithms using $F_1$ to find the optimal
> threshold for acceptance. That is, given a new document $d$, we accept
> it if the calculated value $p(d|E)$ is larger than the determined
> $\lambda\cdot\delta$. For this classifier algorithm we store $\delta$
> and $\lambda$.

A more detailed picture of the algorithm is explained in the doctoral dissertation [Characteristic Concept Representations](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=269394) of Piew Datta.